# PHP: Form submission asnwer as a part of the email subject

Tags: php, html, forms

So i am fairly new to PHP (worked with it a little, not much though). I have a form submission that sends to my email. The thing is, i want to have one of the answers in my subject line. example: they choose bug, i want my subject to be "Site: Bug", or "Site: Other" depending on what they pick for the subject in the form.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {     

    $email_to = "email@email.com";
    $email_subject = "Site: Submission";

    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['subject']) ||
        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');      
    }

    $name = $_POST['name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $subject = $_POST['subject']; // drop down menu
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Subject: ".clean_string($subject)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";


// create email headers
    $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
    'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); 
    ?>

    Thank you for you submission.

    <?php
    } 
    die();
    ?>
```

Any help is appreciated. Sorry if this is a easy question, but i couldnt find an answer using google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the contents of `$subject` in the email subject, put something like this just before email headers:

```
[...]
if ( isset( $subject ) ) {
    $email_subject = 'Site: '.$subject;
}

// create email headers
[...]
```

Comment: This!!!!! Thanks bro, its the if (isset) that i was missing. I had the inside part but it just froze up for somereason. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

if i understood you correctly - just add it to the subject:

```
 $subject = $_POST['subject']; // drop down menu
 $email_subject = "Site: ".$subject;
```

first get `$subject` then add it to `$email_subject`

Answer (score 0):

Add something like this to your form.

```
<select name="subject">
    <option value="Site: Bug">Bug</option>
    <option value="Site: Other">Other</option>
</select>
```